# How can I simplify this expression?

Tags: python, simplify, code-cleanup

I want to check whether some strings and their lowercase variants can be found inside another,but my code seems pointlessly complex.

this works, but I want to know whether a cleaner variant exists:

```
if ("aaa" in string or "Aaa" in string or "bbb" in string or "Bbb" in string) and C not in list:
   function()
```

Comment: `any(x in string for x in ('aaa', 'Aaa', 'bbb', 'Bbb'))`?

Comment: Is `C` supposed to be a string and is `list` supposed to be `string`? Or are they unrelated? (Also, do not use `list` as a name as it will shadow Python's `list` type).

Comment: It would be much easier to understand this code if you posted a Minimal Reproducible Example.  Include what `string` `C` and `list` are, and as bretertainer says, don't use `list` as a variable name in python. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
if any(s in string for s in ('aaa', 'Aaa', 'bbb', 'Bbb')) and C not in list:
   function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex:

```
import re
if re.search('|'.join(['aaa', 'Aaa', 'bbb', 'Bbb']), string) and C not in mylist:
    function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex range, which affords one to easy modify possible matches in the future; you can also add the re.IGNORECASE to make the match case insensitive:

```
    import re
    l = [ "Aaa", "bbb", "C" ]
    for ele in l:
         if (re.match(r'[ab]+', ele, re.IGNORECASE)):
             function()
```

Note: I'm trying to simply the need to check your string and list, but I don't know if that feasible.

Comment: `re.match` only matches from the beginning of the string. Add `"zAaa"` to your list and you can observe this for yourself.

Comment: @braintrainer while it is simple enough to expand the regex to include the rest of the string, my emphasis is on the OP reducing the string and list into just a list, so they can iterate through it.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding. Is `l` supposed to be a tokenized version of OP's `string`?

Comment: @brentertainer, Yes. ...In doing so, I'm "asking" for a reconsideration of the string and list, since, IMO, that's the path to simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me about my wrong answer. I didn't get enough time to test it. I reposted a working one

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another method using list comprehension. Its long though but it works:

```
if True in [1 for _ in ["aaa","Aaa","Bbb","bbb"] if _ in string] and C not in list:
    function()
```